# SharePoint 2010 - Changing from Kerberos to Claims-Based Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-2008, authentication, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I want to change the Authentication Provider from Kerberos to Claim-Based in my SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition environment.

What problems can occur in my SharePoint environment?
I heard that there are problems with the RSS Reader Webpart if the Webpart consumed a feed from my SharePoint. It will probably not be usable with Claim-Based Authentication.
Are there other problems like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you want to change from classic authentication to claims-based authentication. Claims-based authentication also supports Kerberos (as well as NTLM). Therefore, you shouldn't encounter the double-hop problem with your RSS reader webpart if you set things up correctly.

I've been using claims-based authentication (Kerberos) for a while now and haven't encountered any problems. On the other hand... I haven't used the RSS Reader web part yet.

Comment: Yes thats right. I mean the changing from classis authentication to claims-based authentication.